# how to stop media player when I start another audio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to develop an application. there are 12 button in this application. every buton plays one different audio. every three button are the same color. I do not want to play same colors together. but I want to play together which are not same colors.

now all of them play together. how can I stop playing same colors.

```
public class Sayfa2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private MediaPlayer sesb1;
private ImageButton b1;
private ImageButton b2;
private ImageButton b3;
private ImageButton b4;
private ImageButton b5;
private ImageButton b6;
private ImageButton b7;
private ImageButton b8;
private ImageButton b9;
private ImageButton b10;
private ImageButton b11;
private ImageButton b12;

private AdView madview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);//UYUMA ENGELLEME KODU
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sayfa2);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3206398076180977~5758879718");
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3206398076180977/5571177453");

    madview = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    madview.loadAd(adRequest);

    sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.a1);



    b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

               if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }


                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.a11);
                sesb1.start();
                //sesbilgisi();

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                /*if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.a21);
                sesb1.start();
                //sesbilgisi();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

               /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.a31);
                sesb1.start();
                //sesbilgisi();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    b4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

               /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.a41);
                sesb1.start();
                //sesbilgisi();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b5);
    b5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

               /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.b11);
                sesb1.start();
                //sesbilgisi();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b6);
    b6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.b21);
                sesb1.start();
                //sesbilgisi();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b7);
    b7.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.b31);
                sesb1.start();
                //sesbilgisi();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b8);
    b8.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.b41);
                sesb1.start();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    b9.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

             /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.fx1);
                sesb1.start();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b10);
    b10.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.hihat1);
                sesb1.start();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b11);
    b11.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

               /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.kick1);
                sesb1.start();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b12);
    b12.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                /* if (sesb1 != null) {
                    sesb1.stop();
                    sesb1.release();
                }*/
                sesb1 = MediaPlayer.create(Sayfa2.this, R.raw.snare1);
                sesb1.start();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    ///////////// SES CALMALAR BURADA OLACAK //////////////////

}

public void sesbilgisi(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder
            .setTitle("Delete entry")
            .setMessage(""+sesb1.getAudioSessionId())

            // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
            // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Continue with delete operation
                }
            })

            // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
}
[you can see picture of design in this link][1]}
```

Comment: Before playing another audio check if it already playing stop it and then play another audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need to check if the color is the same.

True or false boolean could work but you would need to write a lot of code.

I would recommend diffrent instances of MediaPlayer something like mediaplayer1 and mediaplayer2.

The same colors run on the same instance of MediaPlayer. Use isPlaying () to check if the same color is playing at the moment. If true then do nothing at all, if false then start it. You will figure it out.

The SoundPool Class could help also if your audi files are always the same. SoundPool would require far less code then what you have in your sample and is more reliable.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I think this will solve my problem